# Carousel - Take as many images exist in the local directory

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code that generates a nav bar with carousel, I don't know much about html, css and js so I don't really understand how to modify it, what I want to do is that the carousel takes the images that are in the directory automatically regardless of their number.
I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to do it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>`substitute(Filename('', 'Page Title'), '^.', '\u&', '')`</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>.carousel-item {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 350px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover
}

#mainNavbar {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', serif
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', serif
}

.display-4 {
    font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', serif
}

.lead {
    font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', serif
}

.navbar.scrolled {
    background: rgb(34, 31, 31);
    transition: background 500ms
}

.font-weight-light {
    font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', serif
}</style>

  </head>
  <body>

<header>
    <div id="indicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#indicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#indicators" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#indicators" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('img1.jpg');ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80')">

            </div> <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('img2.jpg');ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80')">

            </div> <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('img3.jpg');ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80')">

            </div>
        </div> <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#indicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#indicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
    </div>
</header>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            var $nav = $("#mainNavbar");
            $nav.toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking for JS to be able to access a directory on the users device?

Comment: Yes. So that I can render in the carousel as many images have the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i'm seeing here, all images are hardcoded as div elements in HTML and the JQuery function is simply adjusting the scroll.

What you can do, is initially generate all these div elements Dynamically using DOM:

The issue here is to count the files in your directory, since Vanilla JS doesn't have any support for libraries like fs (Like in NodeJS) it's hard to get a directories length using pure Vanilla. If you really need this I'd reccomend PHP.

Here is how to dynamically generate elements once you've "magically" found the number of entries in your dir:

```js
const baseUrl = "base_url_to_images/";
// Now you want some kind of file naming system, (Ex. I'll use increments of 1)
//So in my folder, let's say I got 5 images that are; 0.png , 1.png, 2.png , ... , 5.png

let carousel = Document.getElementByClassName('carousel-inner')[0];

for(let i = 0; i > 5; i++){
var img = carousel.createElement('img');
img.src = baseUrl + i.toString() + '.png'; //Here you can dynamically generate i+1 amount of pictures 

carousel.createElement(tagName[, options]); //I've noticed that list <li> elements are also hardcoded and probably have something to do with JQuery's scroll, so those can be dynamically generate the same way..

}
```

Here are some sources that might help:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-image-element-dynamically-using-javascript/

Comment: Also this code probably isn't working, it's just a rough idea for you